# Using a generic with an unspecified type parameter as a value in a Dictionary

Tags: c#

I'm writing a method that returns a different instance of a class based on the type passed in, for a load process.

The method I'm trying to write will be used like:

```
Loader<MyType> loader = context.GetLoader<MyType>();
loader.Load(myTypeArray);
```

Internally, I'm planning on keeping a `Dictionary<Type, T>` with the loader as the value.  However, I'm not sure what type `T` should be.

I could make `T` `object`, but I'd prefer to keep it as some sort of `Loader<>`.  I know I'll need to cast it either way, but using `Loader<>` would give a little more type safety.

Is there any good way to implement this?

Comment: OK, let's say you have a dictionary with all these different types in it, how would you expect to consume the contents of it?

Comment: The dictionary will have a key of `typeof(T)` and a value of `Loader<T>`.  In `GetLoader<T>()`, I'll cast the value I get from the dictionary appropriately.

Comment: IMO You're better off not using generics and having each loader implement a non-generic interface.  Cast the loaded object instances, not the loaders themselves.  Though I don't see the usefulness of having a dictionary in the first place.

Comment: I would have preferred to use a generic interface, but due to the `Load` method, that doesn't seem to be an option.  The dictionary matches the type going in to `GetLoader<T>()` to a loader instance, since the loaders are not interchangeable between record types.  In reality all this is a hack around the lack of type specialization in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices. Both require you to add an interface.

1. Add a plain `ILoader` (with no type arguments) interface, and implement it in your loader as `class Loader<T> : ILoader`. The common interface will allow you to store all loaders in a `List<ILoader>`.

   ```
   interface ILoader {}

   class Loader<T> : ILoader {}

   void Example()
   {
       var loaders = new List<ILoader>();
       loaders.Add( new Loader<Foo>() );
       loaders.Add( new Loader<Bar>() );
   }
   ```
2. Define a new covariant interface `ILoader<out T>` and implement it in your Loader as `class Loader<T> : ILoader<T>`. The covariance will allow you to store all loaders in a `List<ILoader<object>>`. This option only works if `T` is a reference type, and is only viable if none of your interface methods accept `T` as an argument.

   ```
   interface ILoader<out T> 
   {
       //void SetLoader(T input);         //Does not compile due to covariance
       T GetLoader();                     //Read is allowed
   }

   class Loader<T> : ILoader<T> 
   {
       public void SetLoader(T input) {}  //Works when not in interface
       public T GetLoader() { return default(T); }
   }

   void Example()
   {
       var loaders = new List<ILoader<object>>();
       loaders.Add( new Loader<Foo>() );
       loaders.Add( new Loader<Bar>() );
   }
   ```

[Code sample on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/scns6Y)

Comment: Your second example is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.  I was having trouble getting covariance to work right in a LINQPad script, but that seems to have been because my test class had a property declared.

Answer (score 2):

> I could make `T` `object`, but I'd prefer to keep it as some sort of `Loader<>`. I know I'll need to cast it either way, but using `Loader<>` would give a little more type safety.

No it will not; this sentence contradicts itself! You say both "I know I'll need to cast" so there is already *zero* compile-time type safety, and that you can get *more* type safety, but zero is not more than zero!

Remember the function of a representation-preserving cast is precisely "I know a fact that will be true at runtime that the compiler does not know at compile time".  **That's the purpose of a cast**.

There is no way to represent in the C# type system "this is a thing of type `C<?>`", so don't try to find one.  You've already embraced run-time type checking, so go for it.  You have an invariant that your `dict[typeof(T)]` produces something of type `Loader<T>`; the only person that can maintain that invariant is *you*, so don't even try to rely on the compiler to do it for you.

Comment: The type safety in this case means that I can't do something like `dict.Add(typeof(string), "Not a Loader<T>");`.  It's not much, but I'd prefer a marginal amount of type safety over none.

Comment: @JulianGoldsmith: You are expecting the type checker to do too much; the type of the thing that is added to the dictionary is *entirely under your control*, and so *you* are responsible for maintaining any invariant you want. This is just like any other program invariant that is not tracked by the type checker.

Comment: @JulianGoldsmith: Don't get me wrong; I am all for type safety. But I am also all for thinking about *what kind of bugs are people likely to write in the future*?  Is it really the case that *anyone* is going to try to put a non-`Loader<T>` in the dictionary, *ever* in the future of your program?  If they do, their test case that uses the thing as a loader when it takes it *out* of the dictionary will crash immediately thanks to the cast.  So the bug you're trying to prevent is an unlikely bug that would only happen if someone adds a feature, does it completely wrong, and never tests it.

Comment: That sort of bug is unlikely, since the dictionary is only visible to the context class, and it's only modified in the constructor.  Still, I'd prefer to have as specific of a type as possible.  Covariance, as in John's answer, ensures that I can only insert `ILoader`s.

Comment: @JulianGoldsmith: Don't get me wrong, I am all for covariance, believe me. But it only works on reference types; if you need to load an `int`, you're out of luck. If you're going to go that route you might consider making a constraint on `ILoader<T>` that `T` is a reference type -- because that really will catch the bug when someone tries to add a loader for decimals or something.

Comment: The loader is driven by class attributes, so I have no problem constraining it to reference types only.  I may be out of luck anyway, though, since the `Load` method requires a parameter of type `IEnumerable<T>`.